# grub rescue, can't boot from usb

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, windows-8, filesystem, grubrescue

I have ubuntu and windows 8.1 dual boot.
Suddenly I got the grub rescue screen.
I tried

```
grub rescue > ls
```

command and it lists down

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) (hd1,msdos1) (hd1)
```

when I try to

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0)/
```

it gives me

```
error: unknown filesystem.
```

for all the partitions. I tried to boot with a usb as well, but the pc doesn't get booted with it. It directly goes to the grub rescue screen. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try the boot repair disc http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ to reinstall grub.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your Linux file system is on (hd0,1)

If you want to list files in the partition try the following command:

```
grub> ls (hd0,1)/
```

(It will only with the filesystem containing Linux)

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
```

Also check the name for your `vmlinuz` and `initrd` files.

```
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
```

(sda1 will change according to your Linux filesystem)

```
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img
grub> boot
```

After you boot into you Ubuntu update your grub config.

Comment: this is the right way. `ls (hd0)` cannot work because (hd0) is just the disc.

Comment: update grub using `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Yeah thanks @LittleByBlue. We don't have this command in Arch. We use `grub-mkconfig`

Comment: really? I am using Arch, too, but my grub is on ubuntu so I always have been working on ubuntu with my grub, see `info grub`

Comment: Oh. I left ubuntu like 2 years ago. :p

Comment: Oh, on `info grub` is no entry for `update-grub`, but I am running it after every system change

Comment: see http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/36648.aspx

Comment: @LittleByBlue Yeah thats the manual why of doing it.